# Android Emulator Doesn't Use HAXM

Tags: android, intel, launch, haxm

I'm having a problem with HAXM. Before I was using Windows 7 and everything was fine but after upgrading to Win8.1 Pro I can't see haxm started message when I start up an emulator from AVD screen. HAXM is installed and working fine, I installed images for x86,my device using it but still can't see confirmation message in launch window that Emulator is using haxm.

Here is the situation ;

- My processor supports vt.
- I have checked my services and all Hyper-VT services are "Stopped"
- HAXM installed succesfully without a problem. (v1.1.0)
- When I input "sc query intelhaxm" in cmd, it looks that it's running.
- I tried using Android L , Android 4.4.2 (got images installed for both of them) with Use Host GPU Checked/Unchecked. Also tried everything with all Skin options and Hardware Keyboard Checked/Unchecked.
- Tried creating bunch of new devices with different configurations still nothing.

I have tried every solution I found on the internet, anything am I missing? Why can't I see confirmation message that haxm is working in emulator launch window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below 2 items:

- Make sure you are creating the AVD with x86 image. AVD manager will not show the x86 option if you did not download that specific API level x86 images in SDK manager
- Once you have your emulator started, goto windows task manager, and look for a process name `emulator-x86.exe`; if you did not find it, and instead found `emulator-arm.exe`; Check your avd configuration as discussed in above point.

If the above looks ok, here is some notes on HAXM installation on windows 8.1:

- I am using win 8.1 too with haxm v1.1.0, sometimes i do not the confirmation message if i configured the webcam, as it opens another window.
- As long as you run `sc query intelhaxm` and confirm it is in `RUNNING` state , you are ok. You can visually see the difference in performance with HAXM and without.

**The below screenshot is on Windows 8.1 with HAXM 1.1.0** -

[image: HAXM v1.1.0 windows 8]

Comment: AVD is created with x86 file image. In task manager I see "emulator-x86.exe" but can't see confirmation message. So, under these circumtances intel haxm is actually working? I will try to start emulators on 2 computers at the same with and without haxm to see if there is a performance difference. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Soulcry in some situations you may not see the confirmation, but in regular use-case, you should see it. If you are using all default values and not seeing the confirmation, it could be a different issue. HAXM performance has visible difference, so you should be able to see it immediately.

Comment: I tried it on a computer without haxm installed and with no vt support. I choose x86 image for AVD but it did throw an error and didn't even start. Tried with arm image and it took much more time to launch then computer with haxm. (Computer with haxm launches it in about 3-5 minutes). In short, you were right. I don't why I don't see confirmation message but haxm seem to be working. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Soulcry I had the same issue (emulator-x86.exe being used, HAXM state is 'running', but no HAXM message) and once I recreated my AVD, I got the HAXM message. The performance difference between when I got the message and when I didn't get the message was like night and day, so I think HAXM isn't working unless you get the message.

Comment: @CodeBling I created many different AVDs as I said before but result was the same. I didn't get a performance difference that is "day and night" but still it was way faster with AVDs which are using haxm images. Maybe it was because my processor was an old one (Intel T9400 if I'm not mistaken). Anyway, I have upgraded my computer so can't recreate the problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Running `\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe`, I was getting an "Intel virtualization technology (vt,vt-x) is not enabled" error message.  I am on windows 7 corporate build and unable to change the BIOS settings.  But by running `\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\silent_install.bat`, I got an "Intel HAXM installed successfully!' message in the haxm_silent_run.log file and then the emulator worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple way is using ARM(armeabi-v7a) instead of Intel Atom(x86)(CPU/ABI).
Hope this help!

[image]